How do koreans pronounce 페이펄?
The word 페이펄 is a transliteration of the English word "paper".
Are there any audio recordings on youtube.com or the wikimedia commons of someone pronouncing the transliteration 페이펄?

Here's more information about trailing "r".
ㄹ coming at the end of a word (핸들 = handle) or before another consonant (맥도날드 = McDonald, 캘거리 = Calgary) sound closer to l than r.  So 페이펄 would correspond to "papal" rather than "paper".
"r" at the end of a word or before a consonant is either left out entirely or written as a complete syllable with the vowel ㅡ, as in 차르 (tsar), 콩쿠르 (concours), and so on.
Many English words with an end-of-syllable r are transliterated without the r, as in 파 (par) or 오너 (owner), because this way it matches the British pronunciation which typically drops such r while keeping the word shorter.  On the other hand, r in words originating from other European languages are more often written as 르 since they are pronounced more distinctly in the original language and may not be understood without it.
To listen to an actual pronunciation, you can check the dictionary page (https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/0f3f21ed4f324c27a1be1bbf8f8e85d8) or translation sites (papago.naver.com, translate.google.com), among other resources.

We say it as "페이퍼". Without 'ㄹ'.
